# PHP store photos in a folder that is not public

Tags: php, image

I would like to create a photo sharing php web site, I am pretty new to you PHP I am used to Java based servers.

I want to provide a form to upload an image. I want to be able to upload many hundreds of images, so it is probably better to store the image in a local file folder, and store a pointer to that file in the database. The reason is because the MySQL database is limited but the disk space is not.

The person who uploaded the image can then share this photo with certain other users, so I will have a table to maintain the permissions for the image.

I do not want this photo to download using a direct URL - a URL should provide the ID for the image as a query parameter, and the server will respond with that image, but it will only work if that user has permission to the file. I know how to do this, by creating a php that will read the file and output to the response.

If I store the photo on the disk inside of some folder somewhere, how do I make sure the photo cannot be hit using the direct URL like `/path/to/photo.png`?

Comment: You can have a php script to load the photo; and the folder with no perms from the outside....so in your php script you check if the user have right to photos or load just the photos he haves the perms to see, so you load the photo, encoded has base64 and display it via php

Comment: Just make sure to store it outside of document root. I worked on something similar and we stored things in /var/contracts/user_id/<files>. use PHPs check for DIR and then make each directory separate for each user ID. You may have to give apache rights to the directory with chown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got about two different options.

First, assuming you're using apache, use an .htaccess file on a folder to make it restricted or modify the httpd file if you can.

See:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html#syntax
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

In particular, the DENY command:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#deny

Either way, php should still be able to access the images since it's server-side.

Another option is to store the files outside of the folders where your php server is located, (outside htdocs for apache, for example). You can navigate through the filesystem using file://, directly putting the directory ( e.g. E:\Images) or a relative path. php is not limited to saving files inside the area accessible by the internet.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.file.php

Comment: I am using godaddy, so I do not know if I will be able to refer to files outside of the the htdocs folder. This .htaccess file sounds interesting, but can you also provide what the file would contain?

Comment: OK so then you want an .htaccess file as i mentioned. Create a file with the name ".htaccess" in the folder you want to restrict access,
And type in 

   Deny from All

On one line. php should still be able to access those files, but other people won't.